# I want to create rpm for Python-2.7.15 pkg on centos 7.5

Tags: python, linux, centos7

While creating rpm for Python-2.7.15 on centos 7.5.
I was creating rpm using below command.

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
.....
......
.....
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UFJQ7P
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/Python-2.7.15/build/bdist.linux-x86_64/rpm/BUILD
+ cd Python-2.7.5
+ env 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UFJQ7P (%build)

RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UFJQ7P (%build)
error: command 'rpmbuild' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Have you considered googling `error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory` ? The first link has your answer ...

Answer (score 0):

`pyconfig.h` is part of the python-devel package on CentOS. Install it with

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

For debian based distros use

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: Hi,
i have installed python-devel-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm using command 'yum install python-devel-2.7.5-68.el7.x86_64.rpm'
After installing python-devel also, i m facing the same issue.
i am trying to build the rpm using below command
# /usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py bdist_rpm